Extracting future climate scenario data by country from worldclim
I am trying to download both current climate data and future data from Worldclim but it seems like I am downloading the same dataframe using two different codes.
I used the following code to download current data:
BIO1_current_data<- geodata::worldclim_country('ZAF', var='bio', 
                                               res=10, path = tempdir())
BIO1_current_data
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 1560, 2040, 19  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 0.008333333, 0.008333333  (x, y)
extent      : 16, 33, -35, -22  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) 
source      : ZAF_wc2.1_30s_bio.tif 
names       : wc2.1~bio_1, wc2.1~bio_2, wc2.1~bio_3, wc2.1~bio_4, wc2.1~bio_5, wc2.1~bio_6, ... 
min values  :    4.454167,    5.708333,    44.58333,    143.0743,        13.9,        -6.7, ... 
max values  :   24.941666,   18.741667,    68.93939,    707.2878,        39.3,        14.0, ...

When I try to extract future data using the following code
BIO1_forecast_future<-geodata::worldclim_country('South Africa', 'CMIP5', var='bio', 
                                               res=10,  
                                               year=80)

I get the same data.
How do I fix this?

Could you post the output of the second code? Are you sure it's actually the same?

I get the same output > BIO1_forecast_future
class       : SpatRaster
dimensions  : 1560, 2040, 19  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 0.008333333, 0.008333333  (x, y)
extent      : 16, 33, -35, -22  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326)
source      : ZAF_wc2.1_30s_bio.tif
names       : wc2.1~bio_1, wc2.1~bio_2, wc2.1~bio_3, wc2.1~bio_4, wc2.1~bio_5, wc2.1~bio_6, ...
min values  :    4.454167,    5.708333,    44.58333,    143.0743,        13.9,        -6.7, ...
max values  :   24.941666,   18.741667,    68.93939,    707.2878,        39.3,        14.0,

Try adding the variable names in front of your arguments. e.g. country= 'South Africa'. Also, maybe this can help. https://rdrr.io/github/rspatial/geodata/man/worldclim.html

It is still the same output as current climate change, I tried with this code as well; Future_forecast_data <- geodata::worldclim_country(country='South Africa', "CNRM-CM6-1", "585",
"2061-2080",
var="bio", res=10,version="2.1", path=tempdir()).  Can you perhaps try it on your computer and see if you will get different results? Thanks so much for your help.

As far as I can tell, there is no direct option to download CMIP6 data by country. And it seems CMIP5 are not readily available either. So based on your comments, this will get you the forecast data you want cropped to the same extent as your BIO1_current_data (South Africa) object:
library(geodata)
# Loading required package: terra
# terra 1.7.78

packageVersion("geodata")
# [1] ‘0.6.2’

# Download current data
BIO1_current_data <- worldclim_country("ZAF",
                                       var = "bio", 
                                       res = 10,
                                       path = tempdir())

BIO1_current_data
# class       : SpatRaster 
# dimensions  : 1560, 2040, 19  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
# resolution  : 0.008333333, 0.008333333  (x, y)
# extent      : 16, 33, -35, -22  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) 
# source      : ZAF_wc2.1_30s_bio.tif 
# names       : wc2.1~bio_1, wc2.1~bio_2, wc2.1~bio_3, wc2.1~bio_4, wc2.1~bio_5, wc2.1~bio_6, ... 
# min values  :    4.454167,    5.708333,    44.58333,    143.0743,        13.9,        -6.7, ... 
# max values  :   24.941666,   18.741667,    68.93939,    707.2878,        39.3,        14.0, ... 

# Download world forecast data
Future_forecast_data <- cmip6_world(model = "CNRM-CM6-1",
                                    ssp = "585",
                                    time = "2061-2080",
                                    var = "bio",
                                    res = 10,
                                    version = "2.1",
                                    path = tempdir())

Future_forecast_data
# class       : SpatRaster 
# dimensions  : 1080, 2160, 19  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
# resolution  : 0.1666667, 0.1666667  (x, y)
# extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) 
# source      : wc2.1_10m_bioc_CNRM-CM6-1_ssp585_2061-2080.tif 
# names       : bio01, bio02, bio03,  bio04, bio05, bio06, ... 
# min values  : -50.3,  -1.9, -12.8,   14.5, -25.5, -69.0, ... 
# max values  :  35.2,  22.0,  95.2, 2254.4,  54.0,  27.4, ... 

# Crop world forecat data to extent of BIO1_current_data
r <- crop(Future_forecast_data, BIO1_current_data)

r
# class       : SpatRaster 
# dimensions  : 78, 102, 19  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
# resolution  : 0.1666667, 0.1666667  (x, y)
# extent      : 16, 33, -35, -22  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) 
# source(s)   : memory
# varname     : wc2.1_10m_bioc_CNRM-CM6-1_ssp585_2061-2080 
# names       : bio01, bio02, bio03, bio04, bio05, bio06, ... 
# min values  :  10.6,   8.4,  45.5, 221.7,  20.7,  -2.7, ... 
# max values  :  29.5,  19.4,  69.8, 729.0,  42.1,  16.5, ... 


@L Tyrone, thank you so much, this has worked.
